# Customized method marking in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, by adding the annotation `@Deprecated`, the method will be marked as <s>methodName()</s>.

For example I would like to mark some methods as `@Expensive`, and maybe show the `methodName` in a different color, or in *italic*, or anything else eye-catching.

Is that possible?

Comment: *YES*, check out [androidannotations in the GitHub](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations). It uses the [Java Annotation Processing Tool.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/index.html)